# MariaDB configuration changes don't take effect

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

The server is working on CentOS 8, I'm trying to configure MariaDB by making alterations to `/etc/my.cnf` but then when I restart DB by doing `sudo systemctl restart mariadb`, the server does restart but no configuration changes get applied.

`mysql > SHOW VARIABLES;`

It outputs the same values. I tried to comment out the including directive `#!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d` and to add settings to `[mysqld]` and `[mariadb]` sections.

`mysql --verbose --help` says:

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf.

The following groups are read: mysql client client-server client-mariadb

Comment: Does `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` show the same values as `SHOW VARIABLES`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether mysql uses the config file debugging it with `strace`:

```
sudo strace mysql
```

In the strace output, look for lines like:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/my.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = ...
```

Make sure openat doesn't return -1. In that case check whether the file exists or mysql has enough permissions to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

When adding additional configuration files, make sure that they are not writable by 'other'. Otherwise you'll have a message on mysql startup like:

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/myproject.cnf' is ignored

and the configuration does not get applied.